# mysql query inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables. in Table-A data is stored and in Table-B comments are stored for corresponding Table-A

Table-A structure

```
id  content     title   likes   comments_count
```

id is auto-increment and content is data.

Table-B structure is

```
        id  joke_id Description
```

Table-B joke_id  and Table-A id is same for corresponding data.

i am displaying 5 rows from table-A with this query and want to display  3 comments for each table-A data but it displays same content corresponding to table-A id data from table-B for all 5 rows. 
will give example to make it more clear

```
$res2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `Table-A` order by id desc limit 5");

while($row2 = $res2->fetch_assoc()){
    $likes = $row2['likes'];
    $comment = $row2['comments_count'];
        $cont= $row2['content'];

$idd=$row2['id'];

$res29 = $con->query("Select * from `Table-B` where joke_id='$idd' order by id desc limit 4");

while($row29 = $res29->fetch_assoc()){
            $contpp= "";

    $contpp .= '<li>'.$row29['description'].'<p></li>';


   }

 }




$output .='<div id="'.$idd.'"  align="left" class="messagelove_box" ><div class="content_box_1">
         <div class="content_box_3_text">'.nl2br($cont).'</div> 

        <div id="header'.$idd.'" class="content_box_31_text"><ul id="commentlist" class="justList">'.$contpp.'</ul></div>



</div></div>
';
  }
```

but it shows same first 4 comments for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backtick in table name

```
 $res29 = $con->query("Select * from `Table-B` where joke_id='$idd' order by id desc limit 4");
```

Live demo :

1. Without backtick : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cefc4/1
2. with backtick : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cefc4/2

Also use `$output ="";` before `$output .=`

Comment: did you also use `$contpp ="";` before `$contpp .=` ? Update your code .

Comment: put `$contpp= "";` outside of while loop `while($row29`.

Comment: Also put `$output="";` before this while loop `while($row2`

Comment: I just used backtick `\`` in table name